# Is it possible to use git-tfs utility to migrate a TFVC repo local copy (residing on a disk) to git?

Tags: git, tfs, migration, git-tfs

We have a TFS repo hosted on Azure devops services (dev.azure.com). We need to convert this to GIT format. We tried using git-tfs utility**(https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs)** to run against the azure devops hosted repo and have got following error .

*_**HTTP code 503: Service Unavailable*

*Your usage has exceeded our rate limiting thresholds. To maintain service availability for other users we're delaying your requests. View your usage on this organization. Please visit our documentation to learn more.**_*

We have now downloaded the tfs source code locally. Can we run git-tfs utility against a downloaded code copy. Can someone please advise.

Comment: Have you ever tried the answer and the suggestions. If the answer is helpful, please mark it as a correct one. If not, we are happy to help you solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. This tool is recommended to use. In your case, it is an org problem. Check the similar problem: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/tfswebapiexception-503-or-your-usage-has-exceeded/1661888

> Since your usage is up to over 300, the page would take more than 2
> minutes to load and wait for load lightened. Please feel free to try
> it again after a while.

Additionally, there is out-of-box utility: [Import repositories from TFVC to Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-from-tfvc?view=azure-devops)

[image]

Comment: The utility https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-from-tfvc?view=azure-devops has a limitation of 180 days of history only. Any utility for entire history. And can you please elaborate how to migrate from locally stored TFVC repo to git?

Comment: @Parab You can find detailed instructions here: https://blog.gft.com/br/2020/12/15/migrating-version-control-tfvc-for-git/